# Unable to livestream H.264 Video with FMS

Tags: stream, rtmp, flash-media-server

I am having trouble streaming H.264 video to my FMS v.5 server.  I am using an iOS app as the stream source; called streamsie.

Whenever I click the play button, it buffers, but never shows content.

Is there a way to resolve this issue, or do you know how to do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

H.264 video via RTMP is not supported on iOS. You can find many topics in Adobe forums.